# How to store data from an each where rows has the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, each

I'm a newbie in rails development, i'm sorry if i can't express myself well.

I've a rails each cycle that do:

```rb
r.round_matches.each do |m|
  m.round_matches_team.each do |mt|
      sheet.add_row [m.round_id, mt.team_name]
  end
end
```

Every round_match has :round_id doubled
The output is:

> round_id: 2      team_name: TEST A
>
> round_id: 2      team_name: TEST B

How i can group round by id in the each cycle and estrapolate the team_name from round_match_teams for every same round_id? I would like that my output will be:

> round_id: 2     team_name[1]: TEST A     team_name[2]: TEST B

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need the minimal code that demonstrates the problem. `round_matches` isn't defined so please edit your question and define it, adding it to your code just as if it'd been there all along. You don't need to add "edited" or "updated" as we can tell what's changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
r.round_matches.each do |m|
  team_names = m.round_matches_team.map.with_index do |team, index|
    "team_name[#{index + 1}]: #{team.team_name}"
  end.join(' ')
  sheet.add_row ["round_id: #{m.round_id} #{team_names}"]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It's works! How can i set a var for team 1 and another for team 2? So i can put in different rows

Comment: @DavideSovrano You can get team with `m.round_matches_team[0]` or `m.round_matches_team[1]`. I don't understand what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this a little differently: I would manipulate the data to be in a better format, and create the sheet from that data.

```
sheet_data = Hash.new([])
r.round_matches.each do |m|
  m.round_matches_team.each do |mt|
    sheet_data[mt.round_id] << mt.team_name 
  end 
end 
sheet_data.each do |round_id, teams|    
  sheet.add_row [round_id, *teams]
end
```

Explained: I will generate a hash with as key the `round_id` and as value an array containing the collected team-names. Then when adding the row, I use the splat-operator (*) to make sure each team-name will get a separate column.

You could even sort the team-names if this might make more sense before using the splat, or instead of using `*teams`, use something like `teams.sort.join(", ")` to combine all teams into one column (if wanted/preferred).